# Intermittent timeout when connecting to Sql Server, what do I look for?

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, timeout

Sql Server 2008 Standard 64bit on Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual machine hosted on a Hyper-V server.

I'm getting intermittent timeouts when connecting to the server.  This happens for both windows and Sql Authentication.  May timeout every 2 out of 5 tries in different applications.

When the connection times out, I can see (in Profiler) that no connection was made.  Firewall is holey, server port is static (good ol' 1433).  If I ping /t the server I get a steady connection that wavers between 1 and 2 ms.

Any ideas what else to try would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out the issue was with too many virtual machines sharing too few NICs.  Once new network cards were added the issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

Is this on a server being hit by lots of users? @@MAX_CONNECTIONS will bring you back the maximum amount of connections that can be made to your SQL Server at a time. If you've got enough users that you're hitting this limit it could be causing the problem. This value can also be check/changed by going to the server properties of the instance through SQL Server Management Studio.

Is there any error on the timeouts? If the applications aren't providing good errors then you could try connecting through SSMS. You'd have to have it installed somewhere off of the server to test it this way but it's easy enough to install on a workstation.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't a max connex issue.  Its not getting pounded at all.  The errors are all simple timeout errors.  Usually immediately attempting to connect again will succeed.